# Create-react-app watch mode fails when file renamed or branch switched

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, craco

I'm using create-react-app (via [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco)) and during development I keep it running in the watch mode using `react-scripts start` (well, `craco start` to be precise). This refreshes the app when I modify code in real time.

However, when I rename a file (e.g. from `Foo.js` to `Foo.tsx`) or switch to a branch where some files were renamed, I get a compilation error (see below) and need to restart the script. This is problematic, because the boot time is significant on my machine, making me have to wait several minutes before I can start developing again.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/foo/bar/Baz.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'xyz\src/foo/bar/Baz.js'
```

Is there a way for the watch script to recognise file renames or monitor the project directory for any filename changes? Perhaps some CRA or craco config, or plugin could achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a way to avoid this? 